# Error installing chaincode in several organizations in Hyperledger Fabric network. Could not find config file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I have been adding several organisations to my hyperledger fabric network. I am using fabric 1.4.1 with the following CLI configurations:

```
    container_name: cli-org1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:1.4.1
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      # Certs
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      # Chaincode
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
      # Orderer
      - ORDERER_CA=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations:/etc/hyperledger
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
    networks:
      - basic
```

All the Orgs peers, orderes and couchDBs had been up, but when I want to install the chain code inside cli-org1 with:

```
   peer chaincode install \
   --lang node \
   --name Contract \
   --version 0.1.0 \
   --path chaincode \
   --tls --cafile ${ORDERER_CA}
```

I get the following error:

`ERRO 001 Fatal error when initializing core config : Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml`

I think the core.yaml is by default inside the docker container, can you tell me if there is an error in the configuration?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below environment variable in your peer configuration.
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic